# SQL Server Report Builder - Show Count of Sub Groups

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SQL Server Reporting Services report that shows customer order data, but it's grouped as follows:

```
Store
    Customer
        Customer Order Items
```

So, each report is a grouping of stores, with a subgroup of customers per store, and then the items per customer.  I'm trying to show aggregate sale and other information at each header record of the appropriate group in the report.  Most of this is working well, but for each store header record, I want to show a count of the customers.  I'm trying to use some variation and\or combination of RowCount, CountDistinct and other aggregate functions, but to no avail.

Can anyone help me determine how I essentially can get a "count" of customer groups to show at the Store level header?  TIA!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CountDistinct` on *Customer* should work fine - no need to specify scope if it's in the *Store* group header row.

I put a simple test together.

Data:

[image]

Report in designer:

[image]

Most important thing to note is the `CountDistinct` on *Customer* in the *Store* header row; this is just the expression used:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!customer.Value)
```

End result, showing correct values:

[image]

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

**Edit after comment:**

Apologies in advance for how long this is getting.

The previous report did have row groups for *Store* and *Customer*, but I've modified this to make it more clear, hopefully. Still based on the same DataSet:

[image]

You can see there are three row groups, and each row in the report is actually a group header row belonging to one of those groups.

In the *Store* group header row I've kept that same `CountDistinct` expression. I've also added a `CountRows()` expression to show how many actual rows are available in each of the different groups.

[image]

Here you can see for *Store1*, `CountRows` is returning **4**, i.e. there are four rows that we are aggregating in this scope, which is what we expect looking at the DataSet.

Similarly, when we apply `=CountDistinct(Fields!customer.Value)` in the *Store* scope we are considering these same **4** rows, and we see two distinct customers for *Store1*, which seems correct to me.

For *Store2* we are considering **6** rows in total, which have three distinct customers. Again, just by applying `=CountDistinct(Fields!customer.Value)` we get correct value.

Hopefully this rejigged report helps clear things up. If I'm still not getting your requirements, can you please explain what numbers are wrong in my sample report based on my sample DataSet? That way I can adjust things easily on my side.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the reply @Ian.  Your proof of concept is almost accurate to mine.  The difference is, I have my data displaying in Row Groups.  So Store is a Row Group, Customer is a Sub Row Group, and Order Items is a Sub Row Group off of that.  So in my Store Row Group, I need the count of the Customer Rows from that Sub Row Group.. make sense?  Based on your example above, you're working with all of your data at the same level, where in my report, it's almost like I don't have "access" to the customer count until I iterate through that entire Row Group..

Comment: Hi, @ewitkows. I've changed things up slightly to hopefully make more sense, as above if some of the numbers are not what you expect in my sample report please let me know what you think they should be based on my sample data.

Comment: no need to apologize, that worked perfectly.  Cant thank you enough, you're the reason StackOverflow is the best website available for Dev2Dev support.  You rock!

Comment: That's awesome, thanks a lot for the kind words - glad it was helpful!